# How to retrieve crash reports from a wearable app?

Tags: android, wear-os, crash-reports, crashlytics

Since Crashlytics doesn't work on wearable apps out of the box, I'm looking for an optimal way to intercept and report any potential exception thrown in the runtime. I wonder why they're not being automatically reported to Google Play Developer Console?

Google already announced that the future Android Wear update will have Wi-Fi support built-in, but even then, not every device is going to be equipped with the adequate hardware.

In that case, my initial idea was to create a subclass of `Application` and implement `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`. Then, every exception would have to be marshalled and sent to a handset, using [`MessageApi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html). An extension of `WearableListenerService` on the handset would receive a message, unmarshal the exception and pass it to, for instance, Crashlytics.

However, that raises a few more questions. There's a risk that the Bluetooth connection between wearable and handset is disrupted, so all errors should be queued and stored on the wearable device's file system.

This seems like an overkill for a simple crash report. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: you may try http://www.acra.ch/, simple implementation, and useful infor provided

Comment: @zeisuke No mention about wear apps there. How exactly would it work?

Comment: i don't know what is wear app, but acra is the 3rd party crash reporting tool, you may download the jar file and follow the step to implement, then configure your own servlet to received the crash report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `MessageApi` for this purpose but `DataApi`. Then you don't have to worry about lost bluetooth connection.

The way it works:

1. when a crash occurs, set a `DataItem` with the crash on the wearable;
2. eventually it will be delivered to the Mobile device.
3. send the information about the crash from the Mobile and delete the `DataItem`.

More information here: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the precious advice. I finally got some free time and implemented it with `DataApi`, as you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a draft of my solution. As [@gruszczy suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29136913/953682), I'm using `DataApi`.

**Wearable Application:**

```
public class WApplication extends Application
        implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = WApplication.class.getSimpleName();

    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, final Throwable throwable) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Uncaught exception thrown.");

        WearableService.launchService(throwable, WApplication.this);

        mDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, throwable);
    }

}
```

**Wearable Service:**

```
public class WearableService extends Service {
    ...
    public static void launchService(Throwable throwable, Context context) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, WearableService.class);
        startService.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_EXCEPTION, throwable);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Throwable throwable = (Throwable) intent.getSerializableExtra(KEY_EXCEPTION);

        sendExceptionToMobile(throwable);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT, startId);
    }

    private void sendExceptionToMobile(final Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable == null) {
            return;
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Sending exception to mobile...");
        PutDataMapRequest putDataMapReq = PutDataMapRequest
                .create(WearCommunicationConstants.PATH_EXCEPTION);
        DataMap dataMap = putDataMapReq.getDataMap();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        throwable.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        String stackTrace = sw.toString();
        dataMap.putString(WearCommunicationConstants.KEY_STACK_TRACE, stackTrace);
        PutDataRequest putDataReq = putDataMapReq.asPutDataRequest();
        PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult =
                Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, putDataReq);
        pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final DataApi.DataItemResult result) {
                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                            "DataItem synced: " + result.getDataItem().getUri());
                } else {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG,
                            "Failed to sync DataItem: " + result.getStatus().getStatusCode() + ", "
                                    + result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Mobile Service:**

```
public class MobileService extends WearableListenerService {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Data changed, data event(s) received.");

        for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Data event type: " + event.getType());
            switch (event.getType()) {
                case DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED:
                    DataItem item = event.getDataItem();
                    DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item).getDataMap();
                    switch (item.getUri().getPath()) {
                        case WearCommunicationConstants.PATH_EXCEPTION:
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Received exception from a wearable device.");
                            String stackTrace = dataMap
                                    .getString(WearCommunicationConstants.KEY_STACK_TRACE);
                            Utils.logWithCrashlytics(stackTrace);

                            break;

                        // ...
                    }
                    break;
                case DataEvent.TYPE_DELETED:
                    // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you weren't using a crash reporting service aside from Google Play Services, it would seem that you could just rethrow the exception in `MobileService` to let the handheld app crash as well for an opportunity for the user to report the crash. Doesn't sound like an optimal experience. Nonetheless, thanks for a thorough solution using the DataApi.

Answer (score 2):

Existing solutions require that the phone is currently in range. With Wear 2.0 providing for watch autonomy, we need to be able to store the crashes and send them over once we are connected. [WearCrashReporter](https://github.com/eBay/WearCrashReporter) does exactly this.

We install a crash handler on the watch Virtual Machine. When a crash is caught, its trace and type are serialized to json, saved to the FileSystem, then sent with a service as a MessageApi Message when the phone is available. Upon reception by a WearableListenerService in the phone app it is deserialized and passed to the installed Phone Virtual Machine's crash reporter.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in following way:
Integrate [this lib](https://github.com/tajchert/ExceptionWear) into your project. This lib will transmit all exceptions from wear app to mobile app.
If you don't use proguard - you can simple use [ExceptionWear](https://github.com/tajchert/ExceptionWear) lib and log exceptions on mobile-app side into crashlytics.
otherwise
When you receive throwable on mobile-app side - you can log it into crashlytics, but there is a problem:
If we build mobile+wear application using [android plugin feature](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#Studio) we will have something like this:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+@aar'
   ...lots of cool libs...
   wearApp project(':wear')
}
```

and apply crashlytics plugin on both applications (mobile and wear) then during building wear application you can see that after proguard task and dex task (gradle tasks) crashlytics plugin doesn't store and upload Deobs and as a result - **stacktraces are not remapped(retraced)** on the crashlytics dashboard:

**:wear:crashlyticsCleanupResourcesRelease//EXPECTED
:wear:crashlyticsUploadStoredDeobsRelease//EXPECTED
:wear:crashlyticsGenerateResourcesRelease//EXPECTED**
:wear:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:wear:generateReleaseResources
:wear:mergeReleaseResources
:wear:processReleaseResources
:wear:generateReleaseSources
:wear:compileReleaseJava
:wear:proguardRelease
**:wear:dexRelease//NO crashlytics store and upload Deobs tasks
:wear:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE

:wear:shrinkReleaseResources**

but when wear app is builded (wear ap is like dependency to mobile app) then mobile app build starts and during mobile build process crashlytics plugin works well:

**:mobile:crashlyticsCleanupResourcesRelease//EXPECTED
:mobile:crashlyticsUploadStoredDeobsRelease//EXPECTED
:mobile:crashlyticsGenerateResourcesRelease//EXPECTED**
:mobile:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:mobile:generateReleaseResources
:mobile:mergeReleaseResourcesknown
:mobile:processReleaseResources
:mobile:generateReleaseSources
:mobile:compileReleaseJava
:mobile:proguardRelease
:mobile:dexRelease
**:mobile:crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease//EXPECTED
:mobile:crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease//EXPECTED
:mobile:crashlyticsCleanupResourcesAfterUploadRelease//EXPECTED**
:mobile:lintVitalRelease
:mobile:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:mobile:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:mobile:shrinkReleaseResources

So, during standard build process **wear** module deobs are not uploaded, but there is workaround:

if start build wear app separately and then [manualy package wear apk](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#PackageManually) in mobile module resources,
then wear deobs uploaded successfully and you can observe retraced crashes on dashboard.

But i personally don't like [manual way](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#PackageManually) of building apk, so i tried to do following : 
at first just build only wear app. deobs will uploaded to crashlytics. then run full build using 'wearApp project(':wear')' feature and looks like it works.

Anyway i am waiting for android-wear support by crashlytics out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems like this library uses a very similar approach, but since I've already had most of the communication layer implemented, I decided to go with my own solution. Furthermore, it uses `MessageApi`, so it's not that reliable (see @gruszczy's answer above). As for your second suggestion - I definitely don't want to interfer with the default building and packaging process.

Comment: @EyesClear second part was not like suggestion, just explanation of crashlytics integration problem and workarounds. So i personally don't package my wear app into mobile manually. I do it automatically using 'wearApp project(':wear')' dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to upload the deobs of mobile and wear within the build process.

Concept:
 1.  Ensure mobile and wear have unique mappings
 2. Merge wear mappings into mobile mappings before upload

1. Configure proquard (usually proguard-rules.pro)
for wear add:

```
-useuniqueclassmembernames
```

for mobile add:

```
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-applymapping ../wear/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```

This change ensures you have unique names over mobile and wear by applying the mappings of the wear build to the mobile build.


2. Configure the build to merge mapping.txt
Add to build.gradle of mobile:

```
// allows to use Crashlytics also for wear by merging the mappings of wear into the
// mappings of mobile
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
task mergeMappings(dependsOn: "transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease") << {
  File wearMappingFile = new File("wear/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt");
  File mobileMappingFile = new File("mobile/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt");
  if (wearMappingFile.exists() && mobileMappingFile.exists()) {
    println("merge mapping.txt")
    java.nio.file.Files.copy(wearMappingFile.toPath(),
                             new FileOutputStream(mobileMappingFile, true))
  } // else we are on the wear build and the mobile build was not yet executed
}

afterEvaluate {
  project.("crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease").dependsOn(mergeMappings);
}
```

Appends the wear mappings to the mobile mappings before crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease.